# Fermat Factorization

Tags: haskell, primes, mathematics

Please review my implementation of Fermat's Factorization.

```
fermat :: Int -> Maybe (Int, Int)
fermat n = odd' n >> (go $ ceiling $ sqrt (fromIntegral n)) 
   where go a = case (try n a) of j @ (Just _) -> j
                                  Nothing      -> go (a + 1) 

odd' :: Int -> Maybe Int
odd' x = if (odd x) then Just x else Nothing

try :: Int -> Int -> Maybe (Int, Int)
try n a = fmap (\b -> ((a + b), (a - b))) result
  where result = get_perfect_sq (a^2 - n)

get_perfect_sq :: Int -> Maybe Int
get_perfect_sq x = if (sq * sq == x) then Just sq else Nothing
  where sq = floor $ sqrt (fromIntegral x :: Float)
```

**examples**

```
ghci> fermat 5995
Just (109,55)

-- prime per http://www.bigprimes.net/cruncher/1300633/
ghci> fermat 1300633
Just (1300633,1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`odd'` seems like a useless function, you never use its result, only its monadic context. Use a guard on `fermat` instead.

```
fermat n | odd n     = Just $ -- ...
         | otherwise = Nothing
```

Don't use snake_case in Haskell (`get_perfect_sq`). We're a camelCase language.

Instead of writing your recursive functions explicitly, try to use higher order functions out of `Prelude`. They more clearly express intent to readers of your code by highlighting common patterns. In this case, having read [Wikipedia's page on Fermat's factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method), the pseudo-code given in the *Basic Method* section shows that the primary operation of the function iterates on changing values of \$a\$ and \$b2\$. In Haskell we can use `iterate` to produce an infinite lazy stream of values, and `find` to grab the first that meets a condition.

```
-- given odd n
let a  = ceiling . sqrt $ fromIntegral n
    b2 = a * a - n
in find squareb2 $ iterate step (a, b2)
```

I'd also be sure to strap a comment to the top with the pseudo-code or algorithm you're trying to implement. It aids understanding and error recognition far easier.

```
{-
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

FermatFactor(N): // N should be odd
  a ← ceil(sqrt(N))
  b2 ← a*a - N
  while b2 isn't a square:
    a ← a + 1 // equivalently: b2 ← b2 + 2*a + 1
    b2 ← a*a - N // a ← a + 1
  endwhile
  return a - sqrt(b2) // or a + sqrt(b2)
-}
fermat :: Integer -> Maybe (Integer, Integer)
fermat n | odd n     = Just . solutions $ find squareb2 (iterate step (a_0, b2_0))
         | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    a_0  = ceiling . sqrt $ fromIntegral n
    b2_0 = a_0 * a_0 - n

    step (a, b2) = (a + 1, b2 + 2 * a + 1)

    squareb2 = isSquare . snd

    solutions (a, b2) = let b = floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral b2 in (a - b, a + b)
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! Could you please tell me where `find` comes from? I didn't see it: `Prelude> :t find | <interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: find`

Comment: Also, as a follow-up, do you typically prefer to use inner functions, i.e. `a_0, step, etc.`? I personally (not an experienced Haskel'er) like to see the types, i.e. I like outer functions. I'm curious of when you choose one over the other.

Comment: `find` is from `Data.List`. You can include type signatures in local definitions (`let` or `where` clauses) like you would for the top-level. It's somewhat less common unless your inner types are complex, but there's no real reason not to. Defining things locally or globally is a real gut instinct for me, usually it comes down to whether I would ever need to test or reference a function independently, and in the case of mathematical functions I don't think I would. Not a great difference though as long as they're all written in close proximity.